# ffmpeg 4 frames left in the queue on closing covert videos to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert videos to mp4.It works fine for the most times.But rarely I got an error like this

`Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height [libmp3lame @ 0x3f54280] 4 frames left in the queue on closing`

This is the command I've run,

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$directory_path_full." -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 ".$directory_path.$file_name.".mp4");
```

when I add `-max_muxing_queue_size 1024` first time  It works fine but later I got the same error as "4 frames left in the queue on closing".How can I solve this issue?

Update1:

```
x264 [error]: malloc of size 5258880 failed
```

Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x5a82b60] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 0x5a82b60] 2 frames left in the queue on closing

Comment: Run your command with `-report` and share report file, when the error is seen

Comment: -report log file have the same content  which shows on the terminal.

Comment: Need to see full report.

Comment: @usertest Not sure if it has something to do with your problem but why do you set `max_muxing_queue_size 1024`?

Comment: Here is what I have for instance: https://mensuel.framapad.org/p/RSx8WONhfG - If I switch to one pass encoding everything works but not with two pass.

Comment: In my case I was using `x264` which only accepts **even** width **||** height

Comment: fwiw, I also was getting the symptom "4 frames left in the queue on closing", after I used ffmpeg to extract a short section from the beginning of an MP4 file, using the "...-ss 00:00:00.000  -to 00:30:00.000", to create a 30-minute duration shorter file.  Then, when I used that as an input file in ffmpeg, to try to change the resolution, that cmd immediately failed with that exact error msg.  Seems to have created a somewhat damaged file. (The workaround was to use "...-t 1800" syntax, which then produced a usable shortened 30-minute file.)  Hope this might help isolate the issue.